# Node js SQL externalisation?

Tags: sql, node.js, external

Is there any tool for SQL externalisation in node?

I thought of creating a JSON file to store the SQL statements but I don't think that's the best approach.

EDIT:

For instance, in Java you can create a `.properties` file and have a keyword for each statement. Then, this file is imported in a class and each statement is accessed by it's keyword. I am looking for something similar in Javascript.

EDIT2:

**Example**

sql.properties:

```
insertProduct = INSERT INTO products VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

My class:

```
public class Example {

private Properties sqlProperties = // load file according to its location

//sqlProperties.getProperty('insertProduct'); will return the SQL from the sql.properties file

}
```

Thank you

Comment: `I thought of creating a JSON file to store the SQL statements but I don't think that's the best approach.` Why not? what problems would you have with using json and then requiring it in? how does that differ from the importing the `.properties` file? You could also use the .properties format if you wish. https://github.com/gagle/node-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `npm packages` they are a useful source or extensions for your `Node.js` solution.

For parsing `.properties`JAVA files you might be interested in :

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties

Then you can handle the SQL calls with for eg:

- https://github.com/brianc/node-sql
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql

Comment: Is there anyway to access sql statements from another file? As I have mentioned, I thought of storing them in a JSON file but I don't think that's a good approach.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a file with sql statements that you want to execute inside the Node.js?

Comment: Exactly. In Java you can create a .properties file and have a keyword for each statement. I am looking for something similar in Javascript.

Comment: Please edit you question to be more specific for others to see and will provide a possible solution soon.

Comment: please provide a sample of your sql query file, so we know what we work with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73254/discussion-between-urahara-and-vlad-matvei).

Comment: I'm done edditing. Do you consider any improvements to this awswer?